# Java Keyboard.readInput() error

Tags: java, java-io

I'm learning java and my programming skills are are good. I have been asked to find out the problem with codes below. when I paste them on netbeans, the error that had been detected was in the `public class CheckoutProgram`  (`String wordIn = Keyboard.readInput();` and `wordIn = Keyboard.readInput();`) and I noticed that the `public static void` method was empty but I'm not sure it has anything to do with the error. I have tried to find a solution myself but I can't sort it out. Can you help me with this issue? please

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CheckoutProgram {
     public static void main (String[] args) {

    }

    public void start() {

        SalesItem[] items = getStock();

        System.out.print("Type item code (press enter to finish):");
       String wordIn = Keyboard.readInput();

       SalesItem[] goods = new SalesItem[1000];

        int count = 0;  
       while (wordIn.length()>=4 && wordIn.length()<=4){
        for (int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        if (items[i] != null && wordIn.equals(items[i].getItemCode())){
        System.out.println(items[i]);
            goods[count] = items[i];
        }

        }
       System.out.print("Type item code (press enter to finish):");
       wordIn = Keyboard.readInput();
        count++;
}     

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("==========Bill==========");

        double amountDue = 0.0;

        for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

                System.out.println(goods[i]);
            amountDue = amountDue + goods[i].getUnitPrice();
    }




        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Amount due: $" + new DecimalFormat().format(amountDue));
        System.out.println("Thanks for shopping with us!");

}

    // method to read in "stock.txt" and store the items for sale in an array of type SalesItem
    private SalesItem[] getStock(){
        SalesItem[] items = new SalesItem[1000];
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stock.txt"));
            String theLine;
            int count = 0;
            while ((theLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 String[] parts = theLine.split(",");
                 items[count] = new SalesItem(parts[0],parts[1],Double.parseDouble(parts[2]));
                 if (parts.length==4){
                     String discount = parts[3];
                     String numPurchases = discount.substring(0, discount.indexOf("@"));
                     String price = discount.substring(discount.indexOf("@")+1);
                     items[count].setNumPurchases(Integer.parseInt(numPurchases));
                     items[count].setDiscountedPrice(Double.parseDouble(price));
                 }
                 count++;               
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        return items;
    }   


}
```

---

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SalesItem {
    private String itemCode; //the item code
    private String description; // the item description
    private double unitPrice; // the item unit price

    // An item may offer a discount for multiple purchases 
    private int numPurchases; //the number of purchases required for receiving the discount
    private double discountedPrice; // the discounted price of multiple purchases

    // the constructor of the SalesItem class
    public SalesItem (String itemCode, String description, double unitPrice){
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
        this.description = description;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    // accessor and mutator methods

    public String getItemCode(){
        return itemCode;
    }

    public void setItemCode(String itemCode){
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice(){
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(double unitPrice){
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public int getNumPurchases(){
        return numPurchases;
    }

    public void setNumPurchases(int numPurchases){
        this.numPurchases = numPurchases;
    }

    public double getDiscountedPrice(){
        return discountedPrice;
    }

    public void setDiscountedPrice(double discountedPrice){
        this.discountedPrice = discountedPrice;
    }

    // the string representation of a SalesItem object
    public String toString(){
        return description + "/$" + new DecimalFormat().format(unitPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Once I pasted the above code on netbeans, these two part of the code ( String wordIn = Keyboard.readInput(); and wordIn = Keyboard.readInput();) were highlighted in red.

Answer (score 0):

`Keyboard` most likely doesn't exist. It isn't a part of the standard Java library. You would have to import a class that uses `Keyboard` if you are trying to use some custom class to read user input.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting the error because you do not have the class `Keyboard`. Check for a file called `Keyboard.java`.. This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using public for a class CheckoutProgram so the file name should be same as the class name when you used public access specifier for a class.

Secondly the Keyboard class is missing in your program so please check with these issues.